# Calling a method with optional parameters from a string

Tags: c#, .net, methods, invoke, optional-parameters

I have multiple methods, some with optional parameters and some without any. How can i call those methods by only having the function name as a string?

Currently i have this:

```
public Method method = Method.QuickSort;    
public enum Method
{
    BubbleSort,
    MergeSort,
    QuickSort,
    InsertionSort,
    RadixSortLSD,
    CocktailSort,
    CombSort,
    OddEvenSort
}

MethodInfo mi = this.GetType().GetMethod(method.ToString());
mi.Invoke(this, null);
```

So, this all works fine, untill i have a function with a optional parameter.. The way i "fixed" it, is like this:

```
try
{
    mi.Invoke(this, null);
}
catch
{
    try
    {
        mi.Invoke(this, new object[] { Type.Missing });
    }
    catch
    {
        try
        {
            mi.Invoke(this, new object[] { Type.Missing, Type.Missing });
        }
        catch
        {
            mi.Invoke(this, new object[] { Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing });
        }
    }
}
```

But this is a terrible "solution", obviously. So my question, how can i create the functionality that i need?(Calling a method by a string name with optional paramaters)

Comment: I don't see the usecase of doing this in comparison to provide an interface and the appropriated implementations of your sort algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can determine the number of parameters from the `MethodInfo`:

```
MethodInfo mi = this.GetType().GetMethod("name");
mi.Invoke(this,  mi.GetParameters().Select(p => Type.Missing).ToArray());
```